# How to calculate monthly return from daily price data?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [27]: df 
Out[27]:   Date                  MSCI USA/CONSUMER DISCR
3958 2018-07-02                  325.810
3959 2018-07-03                  323.680
3960 2018-07-05                  325.550
3961 2018-07-06                  328.050
3962 2018-07-09                  331.890
3963 2018-07-10                  332.650
3964 2018-07-11                  331.740
3965 2018-07-12                  333.910
3966 2018-07-13                  334.850
3967 2018-07-16                  335.290
3968 2018-07-17                  335.990
3969 2018-07-18                  335.740
3970 2018-07-19                  334.870
3971 2018-07-20                  333.240
3972 2018-07-23                  332.690
3973 2018-07-24                  331.600
3974 2018-07-25                  333.930
3975 2018-07-26                  332.100
```

I have daily price data which I want to calculate monthly return. What makes this problem hard is that my data is based on the stock market trading day, not the actual dates.

First day of the month in my data is not necessarily day 1 of the month (`2018-07-02` as opposed to `2018-07-01`.) Same for the last day of the month (it's not necessarily the actual last day of the month).

I have tried:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))
g.sum()
2018-06-30    6884.610
2018-07-31    5973.580.
g_date = g.index
```

which is not what I want because `2018-07-31` does not exist in my original data.

I would very appreciate if someone could share their advice.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What problem are you facing when grouping by the `year-month` set?

Comment: Show your attempts at a solution please.

Comment: @hjpotter92 What do you exactly mean by grouping by the `year-month`  set? are you talking about  `g = price_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))` method? This method returns me the actual last days of the month.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Hi, I just edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do something like this using `agg`:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='Date'))[['Date','MSCI USA/Consumer DISCR']]

g.agg({'Date':'max','MSCI USA/Consumer DISCR':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
        Date  MSCI USA/Consumer DISCR
0 2018-07-26                  5973.58
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for `freq` either `BMS` if you want the first business day of the month or `BM` for the last one, check [Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases), such as:

```
print (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq = 'BMS')).sum())
               MSCI
Date               
2018-07-02  5973.58
```